# Can't catch exception from ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cancellation

Welp, I've this code:

```
    public static async Task TimedSync (CancellationToken ct)
    {
        try {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Run(async () => await UP.Sincronizacao.SyncDB(true));
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), () => {
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                Task.Run(async () => await UP.Sincronizacao.SyncDB(false));
                return true;
            });
        } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
            await Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Got it", "Good", "ok");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            await Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Oops", e.Message, "dismiss");
        }
    }
```

The app just crashes at this point, and on debug I find that the exception thrown by `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` is unhandled.

Edit:
Ok, something really weird happened, I removed the first `if(ct.IsCancellationRequested) ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` and followed Peter's suggestion, the Throw inside the lambda now throws the exception, the try catch block I put on it as well didn't work, but the try catch outside the lambda caught the exception. Here's the code:

```
    public static async Task TimedSync (CancellationToken ct)
    {
        try {
            await Task.Run(async () => await UP.Sincronizacao.SyncDB(true));
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), () => {
                try {
                    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    Task.Run(async () => await UP.Sincronizacao.SyncDB(false));
                    return true;
                } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
            await Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Got it", "Good", "ok");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            await Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Oops", e.Message, "dismiss");
        }
    }
```

It kinda works for me :)
But still would like to understand what's going on here

Comment: What specifically is the exception that is unhandled?

Comment: OperationCanceledException precisely

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you have two `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` calls. Is it the second one that's throwing the exception? `Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer` looks like it's a fire-and-forget function, so exceptions from its delegate won't propagate out to the outer method.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown in  the thread where you have your `catch`? I would say, that the problem is, that you need to catch the exception in another thread *(since I see there `async`, `Taks.Run`, `StartTimer`)*.

Comment: If you catch `CancellationException` *inside* the lambda passed to `StartTimer` and return false, that should fix it.

Comment: Actually it was the first, then I commented it and it ends up happening on the second one. And yes, Visual Studio told me on debug it was the `ThrowIfCancellationRequested ` line, that's why I'm so lost

Comment: Ok Peter, I'll try

Comment: No repro. I bet you think you're running against this version of your code when you're running against another version. Here's my repro https://gist.github.com/WillSullivan/6f550f45db2b3f0c7674804c7390052b compare this to your code and see if I'm missing something (sorry, knocked this out in a min)

Comment: you can review this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633903/elegantly-handle-task-cancellation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `StartTimer` a lambda that will throw a `CancellationException` when cancellation happens, but this exception doesn't necessarily fire inside `StartTimer` or the scope of `TimedSync`.

My guess, because I don't use Xamarin, is that the timer code running your lambda sees the exception on a separate task and promotes that to an application failure.

If you catch `CancellationException` in the lambda and return false this should have the desired effect of stopping the timer *without* propagating an exception to the Xamarin timer code.

Note that the direct call to `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` *will* be caught inside `TimedSync` and hit your catch block.